# Which one: moznss, gnutls, openssl?

Tags: openldap

I have an openldap server on RHEL 6.6 which is compiled to use moznss. I am running into problems with connecting, tls cannot start, I get errors like:

```
TLS: loaded CA certificate file /etc/pki/tls/certs/lcni_uoregon_edu_interm.cer.
TLS: error: tlsm_PR_Recv returned 0 - error 22:Invalid argument
TLS: error: connect - force handshake failure: errno 22 - moznss error -5938
TLS: can't connect: TLS error -5938:Encountered end of file.
```

This is apparently a well-known issue, and as of a couple of years ago Howard Chu expressed doubts as to the readiness of moznss.

So, what is the current wisdom regarding which ssl/tls system to use? I've generally gone with openssl, though gnutls is newer, perhaps better?

Comment: Recommendation questions are off-topic, but OpenDSL is easily the most widely used of these.

Comment: Sorry for the OT post. After I posted, I found out that questions like "Which is best, emacs or vi?" were - em - discouraged. I did lots of searching for openssl vs. gnutls vs. nss and got nothing conclusive. There ought to be a place someone can ask such questions as "WEP, WPA, which should I use?" to take an obvious example.